# how to handle media button to stop a song?

Tags: android

I  have one service in which I am playing a song. Now I want to stop the song when I press volumn up and down button.

I used broadcast receiver also with the following code but it doesn't help me

```
 if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON))
 {
      player.stop();    
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Now I want to stop the song when i press volumn up and down button.

The "volumn up and down button" is not the media button. There is no broadcast `Intent` for the volume rocker, so your service will not be able to find out about such presses on its own. An activity can watch for volume button `KeyEvents` via `onKeyDown()`.

Comment: Is there is any other way to stop song in service?

Comment: @user437833: Use the media button (available on headsets). Or, use an activity. Or, use a Notification.

Answer (score 1):

Intent you  handled 'll not be fired when you press volume buttons of device but remote buttons like earphone buttons. I think there is no intent action associated with device volume buttons if those are not implemented in framework or hardware level.
Please have look at it:

[An example of the handling of media button intents](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html)
I think you can catch these key events in onKeyDown() in an activity.

Comment: Is there is any other way to stop song in service?

Comment: I think no, because we don't get any key event in service since it runs in background.