# the possible values of EXTRA_KEY_EVENT from intent ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON?

Tags: android

What are the values of `EXTRA_KEY_EVENT` from intent `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` that can be received by a `Broadcast Receiver`?

Does it including something to identify if the volume buttons are pressed?

Are the volume buttons even media buttons?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"The "volumn up and down button" is not the media button. There is no broadcast Intent for the volume rocker, so your service will not be able to find out about such presses on its own. An activity can watch for volume button KeyEvents via onKeyDown()."

[how to handle media button to stop a song?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825995/how-to-handle-media-button-to-stop-a-song)

Comment: I'm new to Java and having a hell of a time figuring out what the "media button" is exactly. Let me know if you find any quality resources please.

Comment: i think the media button is the play/pause button available on some headphones. i am not really certain though